# upload any Document in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application, creating functionality in which require to upload document of type (pdf/xls/doc/image). After uploading the document that document name should show in screen and on click of that document it show the document which i have selected.

How to implement this functionality, which is the best practise to do this.

Plz provide your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create file using below code. Here it is txt file.

```
NSString *stringToWrite = @"This is my string";
NSError *error;
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.txt"];
[stringToWrite writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```